# How to deal with big dataset when using pyG?

Tags: pytorch-geometric

I am a beginer learning to using torch_geometric to build my GNN models. I refered the sample of [the pyG example of node classification](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14OvFnAXggxB8vM4e8vSURUp1TaKnovzX?usp=sharing) and build my own dataset, however, I tried to use my GPU to run the code and it tells me that it run out of memory, maybe my dataset is too large to allocate the GPU memory? I don't know. I shared an machine of 8 A100 with my classmates. Could you please give me some suggestions, thank you!

```py
from torch_geometric.nn import GATConv,GCNConv
from torch_geometric.data import Dataset,DataLoader,HeteroData,Data
import torch.nn as nn
from torch_geometric.nn import DataParallel
from torch_geometric.loader import DataListLoader
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch
import pandas as pd
from transformers import BertTokenizer,BertModel
import pickle
import time
from tqdm import tqdm
from numba import jit
import json
from torch.optim import lr_scheduler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "4,5,6,7"
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")


plt.grid(True)
plt.grid(color='gray',    
         linestyle='--',
         linewidth=1,
         alpha=0.3) 
begin = time.time()
punctuation = "!#$%&'\(\)－*+,-./:;<=>?@\\\[\]^_`{|}~（）：；，。【】·、“”‘’《》\"%……——·"
def dataCleanifier(s):
    for i in punctuation:
        s.replace(i," ")
    s = s.replace("  "," ")
    s = s.replace("\n","")
    return s



class BertClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,bertType:str,max_length,tag_size):
        super(BertClassifier,self).__init__()        
        self.bertType = bertType
        self.tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(self.bertType)
        self.encoder = BertModel.from_pretrained(self.bertType)
        self.outputDim = self.encoder.pooler.dense.out_features
        self.max_length = max_length
        self.tag_size = tag_size
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.1)
        self.activation = nn.LeakyReLU(0.1)
        self.convs = nn.ModuleList(
            [nn.Conv2d(1, 512, (k, self.outputDim)) for k in (2,3,4)])
        self.fc_cnn = nn.Linear(512 * len((2,3,4)), self.tag_size)
    def conv_and_pool(self, x, conv):
        x = F.relu(conv(x)).squeeze(3)
        x = F.max_pool1d(x, x.size(2)).squeeze(2)
        return x
    def forward(self,x):
        
        x = self.tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(x,return_tensors="pt",max_length=self.max_length,truncation=True,padding="max_length")
        attention = x["attention_mask"]
        x = x["input_ids"]

        x = x.cuda(2)
        x = self.encoder(x,attention_mask=attention.cuda(2))['last_hidden_state'][:]
        x = x.unsqueeze(1)
        encoded = torch.cat([self.conv_and_pool(x,conv) for conv in self.convs],1)

        x = self.fc_cnn(encoded)
        x = self.activation(x)


        # x = F.softmax(x,dim=1)
        return x,encoded


class ContrastiveLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ContrastiveLoss, self).__init__()
    def forward(self,representations,label,y_hat):
        n = label.shape[0]
        T = 0.5
        similarity_matrix = F.cosine_similarity(representations.unsqueeze(1), representations.unsqueeze(0), dim=2)
        mask = torch.ones_like(similarity_matrix) * (label.expand(n, n).eq(label.expand(n, n).t()))
        mask_no_sim = torch.ones_like(mask) - mask
        mask_dui_jiao_0 = torch.ones(n ,n) - torch.eye(n, n )
        similarity_matrix = torch.exp(similarity_matrix/T)
        similarity_matrix = similarity_matrix*mask_dui_jiao_0
 
        sim = mask*similarity_matrix


        no_sim = similarity_matrix - sim
       
        no_sim_sum = torch.sum(no_sim , dim=1)
       
        no_sim_sum_expend = no_sim_sum.repeat(n, 1).T
        sim_sum  = sim + no_sim_sum_expend
        loss = torch.div(sim , sim_sum)
       
        loss = mask_no_sim + loss + torch.eye(n, n )
        #接下来就是算一个批次中的loss了
        loss = -torch.log(loss)  #求-log
        loss = torch.sum(torch.sum(loss, dim=1) )/(2*n)+nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(y_hat,label)
        return loss

class GAT(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_channels) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = GATConv(data.num_features,hidden_channels)
        self.conv2 = GATConv(hidden_channels,9)
        self.activation = nn.ReLU()
    def forward(self,x,edge_index):
        
        x = self.conv1(x,edge_index)
        x = self.activation(x)
        # print(x)
        # x = F.dropout(x,p=0.2)
        x = self.conv2(x,edge_index)
        return x

x=None
y=None
edge_index = None
train_mask = None
with open("X.pkl","rb") as f1:
    x = pickle.load(f1)

with open("Y.pkl","rb") as f2:
    y = pickle.load(f2)
    y = y.long()

with open("edge_index.pkl","rb") as f3:
    edge_index = pickle.load(f3)

    # print(edge_index.shape)

with open("train_mask.pkl","rb") as f4:
    train_mask = pickle.load(f4)

data = Data(x=x,y=y,edge_index=edge_index)

data.train_mask = train_mask


model = GAT(hidden_channels=32)
model.cuda()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, 100, 0.8)

criterion = ContrastiveLoss()
def train():
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear gradients.
    out = model(data.x,data.edge_index)  # Perform a single forward pass.

    loss = criterion(data.x[data.train_mask], data.y[data.train_mask],out[data.train_mask])  # Compute the loss solely based on the training nodes.
    loss.backward()  # Derive gradients.
    optimizer.step()  # Update parameters based on gradients.
    return loss

def test():
    model.eval()
    out = model(data.x, data.edge_index)
    pred = out.argmax(dim=1)  # Use the class with highest probability.
    test_correct = pred[data.train_mask] == data.y[data.train_mask]  # Check against ground-truth labels.
    test_acc = int(test_correct.sum()) / int(data.train_mask.sum())  # Derive ratio of correct predictions.
    return test_acc

accs = []
for epoch in range(1, 1025):
    loss = train()
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch:03d}, Loss: {loss:.4f}',end=" ")
    acc = test()
    print("acc:",acc)
    accs.append(acc)
    scheduler.step()
plt.plot(range(len(accs)),accs)
print(time.time()-begin)
with open("./accs_gat_GCL.pkl","wb") as f1:
    pickle.dump(accs,f1)
plt.savefig("./res_GAT_GCL.png",dpi=600)
```

I have tried to use DataPararel to use multiple GPU to load my model and dataset but failed.